# How can I use Kivy TextInput to assign attributes to an object?

Tags: python, kivy

I've coded off and on as a hobby since the pandemic, and feel like I've gotten the hang of OOP and have began working on a basketball simulator. I've created a simulator uses a Player and Team class to simulate full basketball games, and now I'm looking to create a GUI using Kivy. I've watched dozens of tutorials, but I can't find anything that makes sense for what I already understand about Python.

I'd like to have a screen where the user can set attributes 1-99 for each player's offense and defense attribute using Kivy TextInput's, and have those values be assigned to each player.offense, so that when I hit "run," it runs my actual game script.

This is probably a stupid question and I just need to keep digging until I figure it out, but if anyone else had a similar mental barrier when learning Kivy, I'd love to hear how you made it make sense. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example showing how to assign a value to an attribute from a text input:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput



kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    text: your_textinput
    orientation: 'vertical'

    TextInput:
        id: your_textinput
    Button:
        text: 'click'
        on_press: app.clicked()

'''


class MyApp(App):
    my_attribute = StringProperty()

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def clicked(self):
        self.my_attribute = self.root.ids.your_textinput.text
        print(self.my_attribute)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Probably `self.root.ids.your_textinput.text` is the most important part of it.

It goes as follow:

1. `self` is MyApp class
2. `root` is the main widget inside the app which is `BoxLayout` in this example
3. `ids` is a dictionary containing items that you assigned in your kv language code.
4. `your_textinput`: is the id we assigned to `TextInput` in kv language code
5. `text` is an attribute of the `TextInput` where the input is stored

Sometimes it gets trick to find which is root and which ids is under what object. You can use print with `dir()` and `__class__`  to detect it.

for example:
You can find if `root` has an ids attribute by using dir() on root:

```py
print(dir(self.root))
```

You can also know what type of class is it by using:

```py
print(self.root.__class__)
```

which give:

```py
<class 'kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout'>
```

You can also use `__doc__` if you added proper comments to your code.

```
print(self.__doc__)
```

Gives:

```
    Main app class
```

You can read more about ids here:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.ids

Hope this is helpful and wish you enjoyable time using Kivy.